# How to preserve loaded javascript content in a WebView when loading a new page?

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webview, state

In a WebView I can load javascript code by running `view.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` or loading the code directly in the JS context you can retrieve via `view.mainFrame.javaScriptContext`.

However, when I navigate to a new URL (be it in the WebView.mainFrame or in Javascript, e.g. by setting `window.location`) all my javascript code is lost and I have to load it again. This is especially a problem when I navigate in JS code and want to continue after that in my script. Is there a way to avoid clearing all JS and in particular prevent stopping the current JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out it's not possible to prevent the context recreation. Instead I ended up with a standalone JSContext instance (manually created) and a WebView instance I set as variable in that context. This way you can run your javascript in the standalone context but use the WebView to do all the web work. The big disadvantage is that you cannot simply act on the DOM but have either to provide manipulation functions in your context (mapping to the the WebView instance) or create an extension for all WebView class (DOMDocument etc.) that publish their methods to JS. That way you can directly act on the swift/obj-c classes.